# customize a PDO Fetch mode

Tags: pdo

I have a PDO class that uses setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, get_called_class() ),

but right now I'm devoloping a class 'factory', that maps a table passed via constructor, and so, instead of having the table fields as members of a class mapping the tables to be fetched I have an array of fields to be matched!

So far so good! I think!

But I need to adapt my PDO class and I don't know how to tell it to map to an associative array instead of class member!

Can anyone give me an hint please?

in my class factory I have the following:

```
class factory extends Database
{

public $fields = array();
public $fieldnames  = array();
public $fieldvalues = array();

// Nomes das colunas com datas de criação e alteração do registo
static protected $insert_timestamp = 'datacriado';
static protected $update_timestamp = 'dataalterado';

// Array com defaults que são aplicados ao objecto antes de gravação na BD
static protected $defaults = array();

// Nome da tabela na base de dados
public $TABLENAME = "";

/*********************************************************************
/   Construtor.
*********************************************************************/
public function __construct($map)
{
    parent::__construct();

    $fp=fopen($map,"r");
    $map=fgets($fp);
    fclose($fp);
    $mapArr=explode(":",$map);
    $this->TABLENAME=$mapArr[0];
    $map=$map[1];
    $mapArr=explode(";",$map);
    foreach($mapArr as $v)
    {
        array_push($fieldnames,$v);
        array_push($fieldvalues,":".$v);
        array_push($fields[$v],'');
    }



    // definir DEFAULTS se houver

}
```

}

I want PDO to give me an array of $fields instead of an array of class instances.

Comment: My objective is to make my framework able to create tables and respective maps in runtime and still be able to use its tools!

Comment: would adding a public $map to the factory and change the PDO call to $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, get_called_class(), $this->map ); Solve the problem? I'm going to try this now! But I've got several classes to adapt before I can really test this! Any hint is welcomed!Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I grabbed the solution, use setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) and make a function to parse the result via $this-map and return the parsed result instead of the PDO result himself!

Please comment! I'm not 100% sure about this solution! I believe this will work, but I also believe it must be a better way!